# Nested Linklists

Tags: java, orientdb

I have an Orient database that I'm trying to create.

A campaign has one or more questions.  A question has one or more call agent questions.

Here are the stripped down POJO's that I'm using to create the database.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

public class Campaign {

    @Id
    private String recordID;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Question> questions;

}

class Question {

    @Id
    private String recordID;

    private String question;

    @OneToMany
    private List<CallAgentQuestion> recordingQuestions;
}

class CallAgentQuestion {

    @Id
    private String recordID;

    private String question;

    private long callId;

    private String agent;
}
```

I don't know how to create an Orient database with nested linklists.  Could you point me to a document that explains how to code this?